# Making Java GUI changes appear during Eclipse debug session

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, debugging

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Debug_Q1 {
    protected static JButton[] t = new JButton[5];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                showButtons();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void showButtons() {
        int     i, y = 30, wid = 50, ht = 50;

        if (!javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread())  {
            System.err.println("NOT on the 'Event Dispatching Thread'");
            return;                                 // abort
        }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Debug Buttons");
        frame.setBounds(350,55, 330,160);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        JPanel bBoard = new JPanel();               
        bBoard.setLayout(null);
        JButton setCaps = new JButton("Set Captions");
        setCaps.setBounds(100, 90, 120, 30);
        setCaps.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                showSetup();
            }
        });

        bBoard.add(setCaps);
        bBoard.setVisible(true);

        for (i = 0;  i < 5;  i++) {
            t[i] = new JButton();                   // new JBtn
            t[i].setBounds(i*60+10, y, wid, ht);    // * set loc & size
            bBoard.add(t[i]);                       // * add to panel
        }
        frame.add(bBoard);                          // add panel to frame
    }

    public static void showSetup() {
        for (int i = 0;  i < 5;  i++) {
            if (i%2 == 1) t[i].setText("");
            else          t[i].setText(Integer.toString(i));
        }
    }
}
```

I have edited my original question to show a complete code example 
(above).  If I set a breakpoint in the showSetup() loop and step 
through the loop, the captions do not update when setText() is 
executed.  How can I force that to happen?

I am working on a Java Swing program with a simple GUI: JFrame, 
JPanel, and several JButtons.  During execution, I change the text of
the buttons.  But in the Eclipse Neon Debug Perspective, these text 
changes do not appear until the program stops, waiting for the next 
user input.  How can I make the changes appear as I step through the 
code?

Comment: 'public static void showSetup() {`char ch;`

Comment: Edit the question and add the code in the question.

Comment: "t" is an array of JButtons. "recs" is a String[].  This code works fine in normal execution.  But in the Debug Perspective the button captions do not appear one by one, each time through the loop.

Comment: `public static void showSetup(int incr) {
     char  ch;
     
     for (int i = 0;  i < 81;  i++) {     // restore this 
      ch = recs[recNo].charAt(i+1);    // * Starter Set
      if (ch == 48) t[i].setText("");    // *
      else     t[i].setText(Character.toString(ch));
     }`

Comment: Hi, greg-449. Did my complete example behave for you the same as it did for me?

Comment: Hello, greg-449 et al.  I am quite amazed that there isn't a fairly simple solution to this debugging problem, and that I seem to be the first one to experience it.  I had to laboriously print out what should have been visible GUI changes in order to debug my code.